# Odd behaviour when opening a WPF Window from WinForms

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, winforms, office-interop

When displaying a WPF window from an Excel addin, I'm encountering odd behaviour whenever I show it with `myWindow.Show()` rather than `myWindow.ShowDialog()`. Thus far everything has worked fine when using the latter. However, it would be nice to be able to display a window such that the user can interact with Excel at the same time - i.e. the behaviour I'd expect from `Show()`.

The problem is that controls in my form start acting very oddly quite quickly. `ComboBox` dropdowns collapse immediately, and textbox input ends up in whatever cell is selected in the Excel worksheet that's active.

I've noticed that with `ShowDialog`, Snoop is able to attach to my window as well, whereas with Show, I get an error amounting to "Could not find a PresentationSource to attach to". I'm not, however, completely sure if that's related.

Obviously one solution would be to stop directly showing a WPF window from WinForms; I expect the problem to largely go away if I change my window into a UserControl and chuck it into an `ElementHost`. However, I'd rather avoid that if I can.

Current code (roughly)

```
public void DoOpenWindow(Office.IRibbonControl button)
{
    var myWindow = new myWindow();
    // This hasn't addressed the issue, though may be sensible to include:
    //ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(myWindow);

    // This *also* didn't work, and essentially set my window to 
    // be always on top of Excel
    //var hwSrc = HwndSource.FromVisual(myWindow );
    //var ownerHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(myWindow );
    //ownerHelper.Owner = (IntPtr)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd;

    // with ShowDialog() this works fine...
    myWindow .Show();
}
```

Current thoughts are:

- I'm getting window messages from Excel forwarded to `myWindow`, some of which it isn't expecting.
- Excel is intercepting messages meant for my window (keyboard and mouse), which is *probably* what `ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(myWindow)` is intended to solve (but either I'm using it wrong, or it's not the whole solution).